# the continue of loop operation goes wrong

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for cluster in range(self.number_of_clusters):
    if type(optRes[cluster]) == None:
        continue
```

when the condition is true, it doesn't come back to the first line of loop!,
what should I do?!,
I appreciate your support.

Comment: `type(X)` is never `None`, the condition is **always** false. Other than that what do you mean by "it doesn't come back to the first line"? Also your code behaves exactly the same regardless of whether the condition is true or false.

Comment: `type(None) ->  <class 'NoneType'>`

Comment: Maybe you mean `if optRes[cluster] is None`?

Comment: I read your question like the one's from the `destroyed in seconds`

Answer (score 2):

Do this instead:

```
for cluster in range(self.number_of_clusters):
    if not optRes[cluster]:
        continue
```

type(`some null value`) can never be `None`.

Comment: It makes this value error:     ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()